# t.props.select is not a function in react JS code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need small help regarding custom component called as SectionButton who acts as button and perform operation on click of button. Whenever for first time I tried to click to button it wont work but for second time it do work properly and I am not getting why it didn't work.

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './section-button.scss';

class SectionButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  render() {
    let classButton = "section-button";
    this.props.type == "form" ? classButton += " form" : "";
    this.props.type == "done" ? classButton += " done" : "";
    this.props.active == true ? classButton += " active" : "";
    return (
      <div className={classButton} onClick={() => this.props.select(this.props.typeMethod || "")}>
        <span>{this.props.title}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SectionButton;
```

Where the type method is

```
<SectionButton title="Use a Card" type="form" active={this.state.methodPay == "card" ? true : false}
                               typeMethod={"card"} select={this.changeMethodPay}/>
```

But when I click another button without typemethod tag in that it won't work for first time.

Here is that button :

```
<div className="button-form" onClick={this.state.activeContinue ? this.state.paymentmethod === "Enter New Method" ? this.goToPay : this.confirmationPay : ()=>{}}>
              <SectionButton title={this.state.paymentmethod !== "Enter New Method" ? "REVIEW PAYMENT" : "NEXT"}  type="form" active={this.state.activeContinue}/>
            </div>
```

The error we  got on inspect

[image: Error]

Comment: `<SectionButton title={this.state.paymentmethod !== "Enter New Method" ? "REVIEW PAYMENT" : "NEXT"}  type="form" active={this.state.activeContinue}/>` The second button needs a `select` prop.

Comment: @NicholasTower What should I pass to select button then bit confuse either to send empty of send a typemethod

Comment: What do you want to happen when the button is pressed? Pass a function that does that. If you don't want to do anything, then either pass a function that does nothing, or modify SectionButton to check whether the select prop is undefined before trying to call it.